# No more than one vaule being passed from a form in rails from multiple collection_select boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have players and fixtures that are in a HABTM relationship. This works well however when I am trying to add more that one player to the fixture using the following in my create new fixture view:

```
<li>Player 1<%= f.collection_select(:player_ids, Player.all, :id, :first_name, :prompt => true) %></li>
```

Only one player is submitted.

**Controller**

I have this at the moment in my fixture Controller

```
def create

@fixtures = Fixture.new(params[:fixture])
if @fixtures.save
  flash[:notice] = "Fixture Created"
  redirect_to(:action =>'list')
else
  render('new')
 end
end
```

**View**

```
<%=form_for(@fixtures, :url => {:action =>'create'}) do |f| %>
<li>Player 1<%= f.collection_select(:player_ids, Player.all, :id, :first_name, :prompt => true) %></li>
<li>Player 2<%= f.collection_select(:player_ids, Player.all, :id, :first_name, :prompt => true) %></li>
<li>Player 3<%= f.collection_select(:player_ids, Player.all, :id, :first_name, :prompt => true) %></li>
```

Could anyone help me out? I would prefer check boxes or a multiple select box where i could hold shift however I am finding these really hard to use. This I managed to submit values.

Thanks

If anyone needs any more informations on controllers or models I can edit these in to the quesiton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need appropriate naming of fields. Each select must have name like `fixture[player_ids][]`

I doubt this is possible with #collection_select method, try more common #select_tag instead

Comment: Naming of fields being where I have put player 1 at the moment? 

Tried this however to no avail. I am not sure where to put this however I sort of know what you are tring to do.

Comment: Hi, I had a similar issue recently which drove me crazy. Mine was a naming issue...As Mik_Die suggested, it is most probably a naming issue. Pls post you controller and view (includind form_for) code. Maybe one of us could suggest a solution.